# Chrome 63 changing http to https

Tags: google-chrome, http, https

Does using Chrome v.63 force use of https?

I am running Apache 2.4.27 on a Windows 10 desktop as a sandbox where I can experiment and do some tutorials.  I have a virtual host setup called www.tutorial.dev with an alias of tutorial.dev.  In the Windows 10 hosts file I have set up www.tutorial.dev and tutorial.dev to point to localhost.

As of yesterday the url http://tutorial.dev/Bootstrap4FromScratch/ was working normally.  In this case providing a directory listing as a jump off point into various examples and exercises.  Today, when I type in the url Chrome changes it to https and I get a connection refused message.

I understand the connection refused message.  There are no certificates setup.

The only change I can find is that Chrome changed from v.62.x to v.63.x.  What in Chrome 63 could be forcing http to https?

I don't have this problem with MS Edge.  I tested another similar configuration on a different machine that was in the process of downloading Chrome 63.x.  It already had 62.x installed.  It worked until the 63.x upgrade was complete then the same problem occurred.

Additional information: If I use http://localhost to bring up the index.html or version.php in the htdocs directory the switch from http to https does not happen.  The virtual host www.tutorial.dev resides in another directory outside of htdocs.

If this has been asked and answered please point me to the question/answer thread.

Thanks in advance,

Barry

Comment: Using the latest version of Chrome and this is the message that I see: This site can’t be reached

This site on the company, organization or school intranet has the same URL as an external website. 

Try contacting your system administrator.
ERR_ICANN_NAME_COLLISION

Comment: I thought the order of name resolution was local hosts file and then DNS or else this would not have worked to begin with.  Or continue to work with MS Edge.  Do I have this reversed?

Comment: Received this comment from the Google Chrome Help Forum: Rong Jie said:
Hi Barry,

.dev is owned by Google and on the HSTS list that forces HTTPS, change it to .something else and it should work again.

Cheers,
Rong Jie  

I had hoped that since my .dev url looped back to the localhost I would be able to bypass any kind of shenanigans like this.  Oh well.  Does anyone have anymore information on this or bypassing this?

Comment: Here is additional information I received from the Google Chrome Help Forum.  See also references in:

https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/669923
https://security.googleblog.com/2017/09/broadening-hsts-to-secure-more-of-web.html
https://textslashplain.com/2017/12/05/strict-transport-security-for-dev

Comment: Had a similar, bizarre (read the comments!) issue involving proxy auto-config files. Literally the bug appears to depend on host name! https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=797011

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Google owns the [.dev TLD](https://icannwiki.org/.dev) and with Chrome 63 they are forcing HTTPS on all requests to anything.dev

I went through my local dev setup and replaced all references to .dev with .local, works fine now.

<s>Your other option is to use Firefox for local development. [.dev now triggers https in FF (since before FF61) with a workaround](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1209387)</s>

**Edit** (asside):
I have switched to using .localhost for dev as browsers allow `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` (blocked if site is not HTTPS).

Comment: "Use Firefox" is not a viable long-term solution as the HSTS preload list is used by all major browsers.  Also, .dev is a real TLD like, say, .io.  By using fake domain names you run the risk of name collisions in the future with real .dev domain names.  If you want to stick with fake domain names for local development, the best alternative, per RFC 2606, is .test.  It's guaranteed to never be delegated and it's semantically correct for this use case.

Comment: @CydeWeys you are absolutely right, which is why I switched my .dev to .local. The thing is, if you want to, you can set your local sites to .com and the browser won't mess with it, this issue is particular to .dev and Google Chrome.

Comment: This change is retarded. Surely they knew that this would screw over many web developers.

Comment: @Duncanmoo You risk running into all sorts of name collision problems when running on domain names that might exist, like .com domain names (or soon .dev domain names).  It's really not worth the headache.  Best to use either a domain name that you actually own, or failing that, use one of the reserved TLDs like .test that is guaranteed never to exist.  HSTS preloading treatment in browsers is one of the many issues that you can run into when your fake name collides with a real name.

Comment: I use ".ved" (dev backwards)

Comment: Currently, a quick-and-dirty workaround is to use IE or Edge, which (as yet) don't use Upgrade-Insecure-Requsts. It helped me to to debug my HTTP traffic. :-) See [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/upgrade-insecure-requests]

Answer (score 3):

[Google Chrome 63 update](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/669923/2/net/http/transport_security_state_static.json), out December 2017, places  **.dev** domains in the [preloaded HSTS list](https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/) with a rule enforcing HTTPS, no workarounds.

```
{ "name": "dev", "include_subdomains": true, "mode": "force-https" }
```

The "only" way is to switch .dev with something else, like .localhost

[IETF states a few reserved TLDs for development:](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606#section-2)

> 2. TLDs for Testing, & Documentation Examples
>
>    There is a need for top level domain (TLD) names that can be used
>    for    creating names which, without fear of conflicts with current or
>    future actual TLD names in the global DNS, can be used for private
>    testing of existing DNS related code, examples in documentation, DNS
>    related experimentation, invalid DNS names, or other similar uses.
>
>    For example, without guidance, a site might set up some local
>    additional unused top level domains for testing of its local DNS code
>    and configuration. Later, these TLDs might come into actual use on
>    the global Internet.  As a result, local attempts to reference the
>    real data in these zones could be thwarted by the local test
>    versions.  Or test or example code might be written that accesses a
>    TLD that is in use with the thought that the test code would only be
>    run in a restricted testbed net or the example never actually run.
>    Later, the test code could escape from the testbed or the example be
>    actually coded and run on the Internet. Depending on the nature of
>    the test or example, it might be best for it to be referencing a TLD
>    permanently reserved for such purposes.
>
>    To safely satisfy these needs, four domain names are reserved as
>    listed and described below.
>
>    ```
>                .test
>             .example
>             .invalid
>           .localhost
>    ```
>
>    ".test" is recommended for use in testing of current or new DNS
>    related code.
>
>    ".example" is recommended for use in documentation or as examples.
>
>    ".invalid" is intended for use in online construction of domain
>    names that are sure to be invalid and which it is obvious at a
>    glance are invalid.
>
>    The ".localhost" TLD has traditionally been statically defined in
>    host DNS implementations as having an A record pointing to the
>    loop back IP address and is reserved for such use.  Any other use
>    would conflict with widely deployed code which assumes this use.

PS: .foo is also in the preloaded HSTS list

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the advice.  I ended up going with .tst for now.  I have a feeling I'l be switching over (forced?) to .localhost at some point.  But for now .tst is less typing.